# Android database memory issue mSize = 1048576

Tags: android, sqlite, uri, blob

I want to get a blob out of the database. I get this error. I am new to the database, what does it mean?

07-13 22:21:10.928: E/CursorWindow(13302): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 3279360, freeSpace() = 1048491, numRows = 1

It seems that I just have 1MB. Is this a restriction to the database, or is my complete app currently limited to 1MB free memory?

I did not got problems inserting the blob into the databse. And I have closed the db etc afterwards... I am happy, if someone can give me some places, where I may look at.

Best Regards,

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 1MB limit that applies to `Cursor` BLOB data.  Since the limit applies to `Cursor`, you won't see it inserting the data, and only trying to access it.

In general, putting data chunks that large into a database is a bad idea.  Instead, you should save that large data out to a file on internal or external storage and save the file path or Uri into the database field instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick explanation. I am wondering how I did it before. Since I saw it working (maybe the data was a bit smaller?). I want to create a contentprovider for internal data and put it there. Currently I only have the database and wanted it to put there for the time being.

Comment: A ContentProvider is a good solution because you can also use it to serve up the file data from those Uri values when appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Storing large files within your SQLite database is bad practice. Store a `Uri` that points to the file instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your variable which is going to save is too large for the cursor to handle

Taking this extract of my Log as an example

```
07-08 10:39:51.324: W/CursorWindow(9207): Window is full: requested allocation 1249663 bytes, free space 398939 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
```

I suggest using callong the separated methods to call the blob or long strings one by one respectively, as we cannot guarantee the Android OS itself is running this App only, which the other can consume a lot of memory